# access azure files using azure databricks pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-file-share

I am trying to access a file which is Rds extension. I am using the below code however it is not helping.

```
import pandas as pd

url_sas_token = 'https://<my account name>.file.core.windows.net/test/test.rds?st=2020-01-27T10%3A16%3A12Z&se=2020-01-28T10%3A16%3A12Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=f&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
# Directly read the file content from its url with sas token to get a pandas dataframe
pdf = pd.read_excel(url_sas_token )
# Then, to convert the pandas dataframe to a PySpark dataframe in Azure Databricks
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

Comment: what error do you get? what doesn't work?

Comment: could you please provide the error?

Comment: the error is 
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: Check the SAS URL once give the File service SAS URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created storage account and created file share and uploaded rds file into file share.
Image for reference:

[image]

I generated SAS key in storage account.
Image for reference:

[image]

I installed azure file shares in data bricks using

```
pip install azure-storage-file
```

[image]

I installed pyreadr package to load rds file using

```
pip install pyreadr
```

[image]

I tried to load the rds extension file in databrick using

```
from azure.storage.file import FilePermissions, FileService
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
import pyreadr
from urllib.request import urlopen

url_sas_token="<File Service SAS URL>"

response = urlopen(url_sas_token)
content = response.read()
fhandle = open( 'counties.rds', 'wb')
fhandle.write(content)
fhandle.close()
result = pyreadr.read_r("counties.rds")
print(result)
```

In above code I have given File Service SAS URL at url_sas_token.

image for reference:

[image]

Above code loaded rds file data successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

In this way I accessed rds extension file which is in azure blob file share from data bricks.